# SetState Not Updating to fetch dynmically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am learning react and I am trying to use a text input in a dynamic fetch request

My component is defined as ...

```
export default testpage = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({})
    let handleChange = (event) => {
            setState({input: event.target.value})
          }
    async function buttonClick (input) {
    console.log(state.input)
      await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/${input}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setState({...state, data}))
 
render(
      <input type={'text'} onChange={handleChange.bind(this)} />
      <Button onClick={() => buttonClick(state.input)}>test</Button>
      )
   }
```

My problem relates to useState updating asynchronously. If I enter a number ie. 4 into the input box and then click the button. The first time I click the button the fetch fails because undefined is passed to the fetch statement because the state hasn't been updated. If I click the button a second time the fetch succeeds. I have read into the useEffect hook but I am unable to figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: `useState` doesn't work like that; you're supposed to use it multiple times, once for each state field. `const [input, setInput] = useState("");` and `const [data, setData] = useState({})`, etc.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-snowflake-mw026?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to keep input's value directly in the state. The [state value not need to be an object](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) - it can be a string, number or `null` if that’s all you need.

```js
const TestPage = () => {
  const [postId, setPostId] = useState(null);

  async function buttonClick() {
    await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setPostId(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={buttonClick}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The comonent already works as expected - it downloads data on every button click. It requires a display logic and a proper error handling, but I leave it for clarity.

---

You mentioned `useEffect` and here is the example of how you can use it:

```js
function Test() {
  const [postId, setPostId] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getComments() {
      if (Number(postId)) {
        await fetch(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`
          )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setData(data));
      } else { setData([]); }
    }

    getComments();
  }, [postId]);

  const comments = data
    ? data.map(comment => <li key={comment.id}>{comment.body}</li>)
    : [];

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <input type={"text"} onChange={e => setPostId(e.target.value)} />
      {comments.length > 0 ? <ul>{comments}</ul> : <span>Write correct post ID (number 1-100)</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But `useEffect` changes how you interact with **your component**. It runs an effect after rendering new state, meaning it runs right after changing input's value. Meaning, you don't need the `<button>` at all.

Because you begin request on button click it is better to use `useCallback` hook. It returns the same function on every button click as long as `postId` (input's value) doesn't change. You can use this function the same as you used `buttonClick` in first example:

```js
const TestPage = () => {
  const [postId, setPostId] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    }

    getData();
  }, [postId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setPostId(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```